# Find expected value of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$ (Integral does not converge)

Tags: probability

I want to find expected value of random variable given by pdf:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$$

So I have:

$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}dx$$

Integral is equal to: $$\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{2 \pi}$$

So it will not converge for plus or minus $\infty$. Does it mean that there exist no expected value?

Comment: The principal value is $0$. Maybe they want that?

Comment: Well it should be 0, but how do I get to this?

Comment: See [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/36027/6633) on stats.SE for an extensive discussion of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the expected value does not exist. However, note that the principal value of the integral is indeed zero, i.e., if
$$F(R) = \int_{-R}^R \dfrac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}dx$$
then $F(R) = 0$ for all $R$ and hence
$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^R \dfrac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}dx = 0$$

However, the median and mode are well-defined and is zero. This distribution is called the [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).